# How to transform this SOCP to the format required by cvxopt

Tags: python, convex-optimization

I'm new to SOCP and want to try to get familiar with the format and how to solve it with `cvxopt` in python. However, for a simple toy example I'm struggling to get the right input format.

The problem I want to solve has the form

$$ \max_x c^T x$$
subject to
$$ \| A_ix + b_i\|_2\le c_i^Tx + d_i, i=1,\dots, m$$
$$Fx = g $$

The example I came up with has the following parameters: $c=(0.02, 0.06)$. Additionally I'm given a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix $$\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}
    0.000025 & 0.000046\\
    0.000046& 0.024025 
\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
and have the constraints:
$$ \sqrt{x^T\Sigma x} \le d_{max}=0.05$$
$$ 0\le x_i \le 1, i = 1, 2$$
$$ \sum_{i=1}^2 x_i = 1$$

I then first transformed the constrained into the proper SOCP format. In a next step I want to make them cvxopt acceptable.

**1. Transform to SOCP** The constraint $$ \sum_{i=1}^2 x_i = 1$$ is simple by taking 
$F=\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ and $ g = 1$. Next, for the constraint $ \sqrt{x^T\Sigma x} \le d_{max}$ we use that for a positive semi-definite matrix $ \sqrt{x^T\Sigma x} = \|\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}}x\|_2$ where $\Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}}$ denotes the Cholesky decomposition. This means, we have $A_1 = \Sigma^{\frac{1}{2}}$, $b_1=0$, $c_1 = 0$ and $d_1 = d_{max}$

The last constraints of the type $ 0\le x_i \le 1, i = 1, 2$ can be converted into a proper SOCP format by taking $A_2 = 0, b_2 =0, c_2=(-1, 0)$ and $d_2 = 1$. This gives $ x_1 \le 1$. To get $0 \le x_1$ we take $A_3 = 0, b_3 =0, c_3=(1, 0)$ and $d_3 = 0$. We get two additional constraints for $x_2$ in the same way with changing $c_4 = (0, -1)$ and $c_5=(0, 1)$.

**2. Transform SCOP to `cvxopt` format**

The `cvxopt` has slightly different format. The objective function and equality constraint is the same. However, the second order constraints have the [form](http://cvxopt.org/userguide/coneprog.html#second-order-cone-programming)

$$ G_kx + s_k = h_k$$
$$s_{k0}\ge \|s_{k1}\|_2$$
where $s_k=(s_{k0}, s_{k1})$

The solver needs as input the list of the matrices $G_k$ and vectors $h_k$. If I'm not wrong I transfer each of the constraints $\| A_ix + b_i\|_2\le c_i^Tx + d_i$ to this format by taking

$$ G_i =\begin{bmatrix}
    -c_i       \\ 
-A_i
\end{bmatrix}$$ and
$$ h_i = \begin{bmatrix}
    d_i      \\ 
b_i
\end{bmatrix}$$

**Python toy model** I've wanted to test this in python. Unfortunately, it doesn't work as expected and I don't see exactly what is wrong. I'm not sure if it is the implementation or one of the transformations above. Here is the python toy example

```
In [201]: import numpy as np

In [202]: import cvxopt as cpt

In [203]: Sigma = np.asarray([[0.000025, 0.000046],[0.00046, 0.024025]])

In [205]: np.linalg.eig(Sigma)
Out[205]: 
(array([2.41183657e-05, 2.40258816e-02]), array([[-0.99981638, -0.00191659],
        [ 0.01916244, -0.99999816]]))
```

As you can see the the matrix is really positive semi-definite.

```
In [37]: c = cpt.matrix(np.asarray([[0.02, 0.06]]).T)

In [38]: F = cpt.matrix(np.asarray([[1.0, 1.]]), tc='d')

In [39]: g = cpt.matrix(np.asarray([[1.0]]), tc='d')

In [40]: A0 = cpt.matrix(np.linalg.cholesky(Sigma))

In [41]: G1 = cpt.matrix(np.vstack(([[0, 0]],-A0)), tc='d')

In [42]: h1 = cpt.matrix(np.asarray([[0.05],[0.0], [0.0]]), tc='d')

In [43]: G2 = cpt.matrix(np.asarray([[-1, 0],[0, 0]]), tc='d')

In [44]: h2 = cpt.matrix(np.asarray([[1.0],[0.0]]), tc='d')

In [45]: G3 = cpt.matrix(np.asarray([[1, 0],[0, 0]]), tc='d')

In [46]: h3 = cpt.matrix(np.asarray([[0.0],[0.0]]), tc='d')

In [47]: G4 = cpt.matrix(np.asarray([[0, -1],[0, 0]]), tc='d')

In [48]: h4 = cpt.matrix(np.asarray([[1.0],[0.0]]), tc='d')

In [49]: G5 = cpt.matrix(np.asarray([[0, 1],[0, 0]]), tc='d')

In [50]: h5 = cpt.matrix(np.asarray([[0.0],[0.0]]), tc='d')

In [51]: Gq = [G1]

In [52]: [Gq.append(Gi) for Gi in [G2, G3, G4, G5]]

In [53]: hq = [h1]

In [54]: [hq.append(hi) for hi in [h2, h3, h4, h5]]
```

`Gq` and `hq` are lists which is required by `cvxopt.solvers.scop`. If I know call the solver I get:

```
In [55]: cpt.solvers.socp(-c, Gq=Gq, hq=hq, A=F, b=g)
     pcost       dcost       gap    pres   dres   k/t
 0: -3.9965e-02 -2.1105e+00  1e+01  2e+00  3e-16  1e+00
 1: -3.9369e-02 -1.3687e-02  5e+00  8e-01  1e-15  1e+00
 2: -3.3610e-02  1.0744e+02  1e+03  2e+00  2e-13  1e+02
 3: -3.3610e-02  1.0935e+04  1e+05  2e+00  4e-12  1e+04
 4: -3.3610e-02  1.0936e+06  1e+07  2e+00  1e-09  1e+06
Certificate of primal infeasibility found.
Out[55]: 
{'dual infeasibility': None,
 'dual objective': 1.0,
 'dual slack': 0.9204046569064762,
 'gap': None,
 'iterations': 4,
 'primal infeasibility': None,
 'primal objective': None,
 'primal slack': None,
 'relative gap': None,
 'residual as dual infeasibility certificate': None,
 'residual as primal infeasibility certificate': 5.782986313941418e-08,
 'sl': None,
 'sq': None,
 'status': 'primal infeasible',
 'x': None,
 'y': <1x1 matrix, tc='d'>,
 'zl': <0x1 matrix, tc='d'>,
 'zq': [<3x1 matrix, tc='d'>,
  <2x1 matrix, tc='d'>,
  <2x1 matrix, tc='d'>,
  <2x1 matrix, tc='d'>,
  <2x1 matrix, tc='d'>]}
```

I don't understand why. Even if I use $d_{max}=0.2$ we should get a solution of $x_1 = 0, x_2=1$. Any help would be much appreciated. Please note that I want to use `cvxopt` and I'm thankful but not interested in answers / comments suggesting to use another module like `cvxpy`. I have a restriction for real cases I want to work on, after finishing some of the basic examples, to use `cvxopt`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of direclty answering your question, I will propose to use a, so called, modeling language for optimization problems, which allows to formulate your problem in a natural way, and have the language translate it to the appropriate format required by solvers such as `CVXOPT`. The code below solves your toy problem using the [`cvxpy` package](http://www.cvxpy.org/index.html), which is compatible with many solvers, including `CVXOPT`.

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy
from scipy.linalg import sqrtm  # for finding the squared root of Sigma

x = cvxpy.Variable(2) # optimization vector variable
c = cvxpy.Parameter(2) # placeholder for vector c
A = cvxpy.Parameter((2,2))  # placeholder for sqrtm(Sigma)
dmax = cvxpy.Parameter() # placeholder for parameter dmax

obj = cvxpy.Maximize(cvxpy.sum(x*c))  #define objective function 
cons = [cvxpy.norm(A@x,2)<=dmax,      # define set of constraints
        cvxpy.sum(x)==1, 
        x[0]>=0, x[1]>=0,
        x[0]<=1, x[1]<=1]

prob = cvxpy.Problem(obj, cons)  #setup the problem

# instantiate the problem for a specific value of parameters
A.value = sqrtm(np.asarray([[0.000025, 0.000046], [0.000046, 0.024025]]))
c.value = np.asarray([0.02, 0.06])
dmax.value = 0.05

prob.solve()  # solve the problem

x_opt = x.value # the optimal variable

print(x_opt, np.linalg.norm(A.value @ x_opt), np.sum(x_opt) )
```

> `[0.6795 0.3205] 0.049999998463030305 0.9999999999999976`

Note how simple and natural is the problem definition. No need to know the technicalities of the solver(s). Here, `cvxopt` chooses automatically the "best" solver (out of those available in your system and supported by `cvxpy`) for the problem. You may explicitly indicate the solver (e.g., `CVXOPT`), if needed.

EDIT: 
Here's how you can automatically generate the domain constraints instead of manually writing them (helpful when there are many of them and/or you don't know dimensions beforehand)

```
# define the `cons` python list with cvxpy constraints you can specify before runtime (it may as well be cons=[])
cons = [cvxpy.norm(A@x,2)<=dmax, cvxpy.sum(x)==1]

# generate domain constraints on the fly:
# N is the dimension, possibly available only at runtime; for the toy example, N = 2
for i in range(N):
     cons = cons + [x[i]>=0, x[i]<=1]
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer. I do see the simplicity of the solver. Two comments 1: As I stated at the very end. I have some restrictions on using `cvxopt` directly. Without knowing `cvxpy` in detail it seems much more cumbersome to write the problem if the dimension of your variables are not know until runtime. 2: My background is pure Mathematics. I have rather less experience in more applied math. That is why I like to understand the detail of problem, what kind of problem it is, what methods you need to solve etc :)

Comment: @math I am sorry, I did not see your `cvxopt` restriction. Knowing the dimensions only at runtime is no big of a problem for `cvxpy`; you just define variables and/or parameters on the fly.

Comment: No worries....I've upvoted your answer but I wait to see if someone can help me with cvxopt. Do you have a reference for the dimension at runtime? Because in a sense you need to create expressions of the form `x[0]>= 0` and so on for a not known dimension. I do see that this can be done, but creating a varying matrix in `cvxopt` is at least IMHO much easier. I would be interested to see an easy way. If this is off topic, I'm sorry

Comment: @math Thanks for the upvote :) I have edited my answer with an example on how you would generate automatically constraint specifications at runtime.

Comment: many thanks! This is indeed much simpler than what I've expected.

Comment: @math just a final comment. In my experience, `cvxopt` is typically not the best solver, at least in terms of execution speed. `cvxpy` installs `ecos` and `scs`, which are much faster. For my problems, ranging from simple linear programming to high-dimensional semidefinite programming, `cvxopt` is by far the worst option and in certain cases unable to solve the problem at hand. That's another great aspect of `cvxpy`: it allows you to experiment with and compare  multiple solvers.

Comment: If I run your code, python tells me that `@` in `cvxpy.norm(A@x, 2)` is an invalid syntax

Comment: @math The code I posted works in python `3.6` and cvxpy `1.0.5`. You are probably using python 2 (which does not accept `@`). Write `np.dot(A,x)` instead of `A@x`.